# Is there any way to use Chrome resources in extensions

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension that has an options page. And I am willing to style this page same as Chrome options page is styled. I found that there is a file

*chrome://resources/css/widgets.css*

that holds this style (it is listed in "Developer Tools > Sources"). However, if try to load it in my page either directly from HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://resources/css/widgets.css" type="text/css">
```

or from CSS

```
@import url("chrome://resources/css/widgets.css");
```

then get this error printed in the console:
"**Not allowed to load local resource:** chrome://resources/css/widgets.css

It looks like I'm missing some permissions in my *manifest.json*, but did not find anything suitable on the [developer's pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) (notice it lists "chrome://favicon/", but that's it).

Anyone knows a solution?

P.S. Yes, I have copied this file into my extension's folder, and I got what I want, but the smart and proper way using this file  (IMHO) is loading it directly from Chrome resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No, you can't access `chrome://resources...` from an extension.
First, it's blocked on purpose, thus why you see "Not allowed to load local resource." Second, you really shouldn't rely on Chrome's resources, which can change in any version.